# Is it OK to have millions of directed relationships between two nodes in Neo4j? Will it add to latency in fetching the data?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

We have millions of users of can make millions of transactions between them.

Lets say there is a user_A who pays money to user_B on the daily basis. We have a relationship SEND_MONEY_TO between A and B nodes.

A ---SENDS_MONEY_TO---> B

What will be the better design to accommodate this data in Neo4j.

**Option A**: We will create a new relationship edge every time a transaction happens.

**Option B**: We will keep a list of transactions as property of a same relationship edge and append the transaction details to existing list whenever a new transaction happens.

Our queries will look like:

a.) Find number of transaction between user_A and user_B in month of April 2021 where HDFC credit card is used.

b.) Find the total amount of transactions which involves user_A

We are open to any new approach as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume in the future, you may want to add other data to transactions, like the :Card :Device or :Platform on which it was triggered/Executed. As you probably know, you cannot create an edge between an edge and a vertex.

I would therefore recommend to use `(:Transaction)` vertices, with edges to the `(:Account`) vertices. You could use `[:SENDER]`  and `[:RECEIVER]` types for the edges.

Comment: As I mentioned that there will be millions of transactions between users. If we keep transaction as vertex, we will have to aggregate things on run time. 

Like we have to find the total transactions between 2 users or I want to find total money received by user_B?
I can give 1 more query -> Like we want to find list of users who interacts with some user_A.

We want to keep things aggregated on user level

Comment: I'd agree with Graphileon.
This kind of design will generate a heavy load, since neo4j will load the outgoing relations when loading a node. Having one node mit millions of outgoing relationships will cause this to result in performance problems.

Modelling the Transaction as nodes with outgoing relationships to sender and receiver will take this load away since now you dont have anymore super-nodes.
There will be aggregation, but no really heavy one.

Comment: What if we put list of transactions as a property of an edge between 2 users?

Comment: A list of transactions in a property of an edge? If you go that route you might as well consider not using a database at all. Imagine what you need to do to find a specific transaction or aggregate transactions during a specific period …. 
Using Transaction nodes also opens transactions to (:Day) nodes , which in their turn are part of a  time tree, which is a great way for doing time based queries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've modeled this in the past. You might need to make a few adjustments to model it in Neo4j, but the general gist is there. Sample projects attached.

---

> Because a customer might have multiple accounts

**Customer -(CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT)- Account**

> Capture the directionality of the transactions

**Account - (SEND_TRANSACTION)-> Transaction**

**Account <-(RECEIVE_TRANSACTION)-Transaction**

> Here I capture a running total of min_Send, min_receive, max_send, max
> receive, transaction_send_count, transaction_recive_count, etc

Account -(SEND_TO)-> Account

---

I've open-sourced the project here:

- https://github.com/TigerGraph-DevLabs/AMLSim_Python_Lab

Sample Google Colab:

- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QnYXgypDYKMxuGfMLEtWcIVkp61njkrw?usp=sharing

---